# Hibernate add seconds to current time

Tags: hibernate, runtime-error, hql

I want to add 100 seconds to current time in hibernate query language.
Below is the respective SQL query.

```
Update table1 as t1 set t1.timeout =  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL :5 SECOND)
where id=1
```

but when I run this query using hibernate it says `unexpected token INTERVAL`

Comment: Found a solution. I execute this query as a native query

Answer (score 0):

The Interval function probably doesn't have a hibernate equivalent.
It will probably be better to handle the addition in your application code and pass the final value to sql.